# Find the area of a triangle formed by normal.

Tags: calculus, geometry

This is a longer question that I am having trouble with. The part I can't do is c, where you must find the area of the triangle formed by a normal and tangent. My problem is that I can't visualise the problem and am unable to find the lengths of the sides of the triangle. I am not sure whether information from the previous questions is necessary, so in doubt I am leaving in the previous questions, but the one I need help with is c.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y'= 2x-\frac{1}{2}x^3$, the coefficient of tangent at $P$ is $k_t=\frac{3}{2}$, so the coefficient of normal at $P$ is $k_n=-\frac{2}{3}$. So the tangent at $P$ has the equation $y=\frac{3}{2}(x-1)+2$ and the normal $y=-\frac{2}{3}(x-1)+2$. Thus $T=(-\frac{1}{3},0)$ and $N=(0,\frac{8}{3})$. Now you have $\vec{TP}=(\frac{4}{3},2)$ and $\vec{NP}=(1,-\frac{2}{3})$, so $TP=\frac{2\sqrt{13}}{3}$, $NP=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{3}$, and since the angle at $P$ is right, we have that the area is $\frac{13}{9}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't learnt vectors yet (am assuming that the TP and NP with arrows on top is vector notation), so is there an alternative way to go from the coordinates of the points to the sides of the triangles without using vectors? This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: No problem. Apply the formula for distance between two points: $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the normal at P is perpendicular to the tangent at P, so if the slope of the tangent is $m$, the slope of the normal is $-\frac{1}{m}$. That should allow you to calculate the coordinates of the point N.

Assuming you have done part (b), you should have the slope of the tangent at P and the coordinates of T. A similar calculation then gives you the coordinates of N.

Finally, the triangle $\triangle PTN$ is a right-angled triangle, so its area is one half of the product of the base $PT$ and the height $PN$.

Comment: But once I have the coordinates how can I find the sides of the triangles? This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Use the distance formula: $PT = \sqrt{(x_P - x_T)^2 + (y_P - y_T)^2}$.